# GNU Make: warning: ignoring old commands for target `xxx'

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Could you please help me to understand how GNU Make (version 3.81) processes simple Makefile? Here is the file:

```
.PHONY: a b c e f
a : b c
    @echo "> a(b,c)"
e : a
    @echo "> e(a)"
e : f
    @echo "> e(f)"
f :
    @echo "> f()"
b :
    @echo "> b()"
c :
    @echo "> c()"
```

Now I run command

```
make e
```

to build 'e' target. Make's output looks like:

```
Makefile:7: warning: overriding commands for target `e'
Makefile:5: warning: ignoring old commands for target `e'
> f()
> b()
> c()
> a(b,c)
> e(f)
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html gives next explanation:

> ‘warning: overriding recipe for target `xxx'’
>
> ‘warning: ignoring old recipe for target `xxx'’
>
> GNU make allows only one recipe to be specified per target (except for double-colon rules). If you give a recipe for a target which already has been defined to have one, this warning is issued and **the second recipe will overwrite the first**.

But from output we can see that commands for build 'a' target are also performed. I thought that according to description at 'Error-Messages' page make, while processing this Makefile and trying to build 'e' target (make e), should at first place decides that 'e' depends on 'a' and then overwrite this to 'e' depends on 'f'. And output should looks like:

```
Makefile:7: warning: overriding commands for target `e'
Makefile:5: warning: ignoring old commands for target `e'
> f()
> e(f)
```

But it looks like make still remember that 'e' depends on 'a' and not overwrite recipe at all.

Please help me to understand this behavior. Why are commands for building 'a' target still performed, even after recipe overwriting?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The dependencies are distinct from the commands. The dependency on `a` is not forgotten, but the commands are.

Comment: Thank you, triplee. I thought about this option but wanted to be sure. Thanks again :)

Comment: Note that the documentation says the _recipe_ will be overwritten, not that the _rule_ will be overwritten.  The recipe is the collection of commands that are run to update the target.  So, the documentation describes precisely what actually happens: only the recipe part of the rule is overwritten.